# Let $X$ and $Y$ have joint pdf $f(x,y)= 4e^{-2(x+y)}$; $0<x<\infty$, $0<y<\infty$. Find the CDF of $W=X+Y$

Tags: probability

First I have to find the CDF of $W=X+Y$ which I tried to do this by substituting in the $w$ but it isn't working. Maybe I have the wrong bounds.

Lastly I have to find the marginal pdf of $U$ which I think would just be like using the Jacobian but only for one variable so instead of the Jacobian, taking the partial derivative.

Comment: Show what you did which "isn't working".

Comment: I did the integral of 4e^(-2w) dw from 0 to w @Did

Comment: Why? What is 4e^(-2w) in your opinion?

Comment: Because it is the pdf with the given W value substituted in like I mentioned and you obtain the CDF from the integral of a pdf in a continuous case. @Did

Comment: But there is no theorem in your notes saying this is how to find the PDF of W=X+Y, is there? And, as a matter of fact, 4e^(-2w) is not the PDF of W (it is not a PDF at all). By the way, which theorems are in your notes indicating how to deduce the PDF of W=X+Y from the joint PDF of (X,Y)?

Comment: Why did you delete a part of your post?

Comment: I couldn't find one. That is why I asked for some help and because I figured that part out!

Comment: Which notes are you following? (You say that you were able to find the joint pdf of U=X/Y and V=X but that the PDF of W=X+Y is still a problem? In that case, it would be extremely interesting to see how you computed the joint PDF of (U,V).)

Comment: I rearranged so I got V=X and Y=V/U and used the pdf with those values substituted multiplied by the Jacobian

Comment: And what is preventing you from using the same approach here, say to (X,W), then to deduce the distribution of W?

Comment: Because there are only 3 variables in this one

Comment: Sorry but you are not making much sense. 3 variables? Huh...

Comment: W, X, Y. In the other one it was X,Y,U,V. 3 verse 4.

Comment: Yeah, and I suggested to consider (X,W). A pair. Oh, whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(W\leq w) & =
\mathsf P(X+Y \leq w ) & \text{where}\quad w\in[0,\infty)
\\[2ex]
 & = \int_0^w\mathsf P(Y\leq w-x\mid X=x)\;f_X(x)\operatorname d x
\\[2ex]
& =\int_0^w\int_0^{w-x}f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)f_X(x)\operatorname dy\operatorname dx
\\[2ex]
& =\int_0^w\int_0^{w-x}f(x,y)\operatorname dy\operatorname dx
\\[2ex]
& = 4\int_0^w e^{-2x}\int_0^{w-x} e^{-2y}\operatorname dy\operatorname dx
\\[2ex]
 & \ddots
\end{align}$